# Are there Race/Alignment restrictions for classes in the PHB?

Tags: dnd-5e, alignment, class, races

I'm looking through the PHB and I notice that none of the Classes explicitly state an Alignment or Race limitation.

There is flavor text, but there is nothing that looks like a rule. I see some stuff scattered around, e.g., Alignments lists Paladins under Lawful Good. This seems like an actual rule since it doesn't say "Many Paladins" or "Most Paladins" but very definitively "Paladins". I know that Paladins are Lawful Good in older revisions, but assuming I knew nothing about D&D, is there a definitive (RAW) grid somewhere in the PHB or supplemental documentation?

Or is a Neutral Good Tiefling Rogue perfectly acceptable?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no hard rule about alignments and classes, or classes and races.  The book specifies generalities, and also gives counter examples.  For example, in the Paladin class under the Oath of Vengence Tenets (page 88 of the Player's Handbook), it says that Oath of Vengence Paladins are often Neutral or Lawful Neutral in alignment.

A neutral good tiefling rogue is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

Page 83 of the PHB states

> As guardians against the forces of wickedness, paladins are rarely of any evil alignment.

Sounds to me as if any choice is playable, as long as you work the back story right.